# Magento 2 Progressive Web App Issue

Tags: magento2.2.2, pwa

I am using Magento 2.2.2. I want to integrate the Progressive web app module.

I have used [this](https://www.tigren.com/product/progressive-web-apps-magento-2/) extension.

I followed Installation guide given with the module.

From that I found a command `composer require sngrl/php-firebase-cloud-messaging dev-master`.

Running this command provides following error. How to solve it also
Suggest other free PWA extension if there any.

[image]
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what error , you get?

Comment: @AmitBera, this is the error: `Package sjparkinson/static-review is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpro/grumphp instead.`

Comment: @SaravananDS It is warning. Not the error.